# Fulltext search fields and Doctrine 2

Tags: mysql, doctrine, full-text-search, zend-framework2

We're using Doctrine 2 and have some fairly simple search requirements in which we'd normally set fulltext on a field. I've had a good google around and it seems there is no way to do this with Doctrine.

We're using Zend Framework 2 for this project and I wondered if anyone had any ideas of a good workaround?

I don't think using lots of LIKEs in the query would yeild fast enough search results, but I think at the same time using something like Solr or Elastic search would be way too overkill for searching just one field in a simple manner.

Any suggestions? I get the feeling we're going to have to hack something together. At the moment we're creating the database by running the orm:schema:create tool from the command line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply said, there is no solution if you stick with Doctrine2 *and* you don't want to use LIKE queries *and* you don't want to introduce a search engine.

Doctrine2 relies on InnoDB and InnoDB (currently) does not support fulltext. So focusing on fulltext or LIKE queries are no option I'd say. However, there is a much simpler way than using Solr or ElasticSearch, as they are both using Lucene as engine. You can create a Lucene index on your file system (within your project dir) and use `ZendSearch` for indexing and querying.

Require `zendframework/zendsearch` via composer and do this for your search:

```
use ZendSearch\Lucene\Lucene;
use ZendSearch\Lucene\Document;
use ZendSearch\Lucene\Document\Field;

// this is relative to your project say /var/www/site/data/search
$dir = 'data/search';

// Create index
Lucene::create($dir);

// Insert a new document
$index = Lucene::open($dir);
$doc   = new Document;

$doc->addField(Field::keyword('foo', 'bar'));
$index->addDocument($doc);

// Search the index
$index  = Lucene::open($dir);
$result = $index->query('foo:bar');

echo count($result);
```

There is no need to install a binary on your server (like Solr and ElasticSearch) to support search. It's even faster than fulltext search, but you have to keep your index up2date of course to support proper search.

Comment: Wow, great answer.. we'll give that a try! :)

Comment: Your welcome :) The documentation is (almost?) non-existing, but you can use the docs of the 1.x series. The search component is almost 99% the same as the Zend_Search_Lucene component from the 1 series of ZF, giving you the help you need to get everything done.

Comment: fulltext indexes are now supported in MySQL since version 5.6.